# Gap in DIV if other DIV overflows width

Tags: html, css, width

The content div needs to overflow width, but then a gap appears in the top div.

Please run the snippet and scroll right, you'll notice the gap on the top div

```css
#header {
  background: red;
}
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>HEADER</p>
</div>
<div id="content">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG CONTENT</div>
```

How can I fill the gap on the header div?

[image]

Comment: I know you don't owe me an explanation for your downvote, but I'd like to know why did you downvote me, so I can improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that is quite possible. what you can use is overflow:scroll, which will add a scrollbar to the large element

```css
#header {
  background: red;
}
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>HEADER</p>
</div>
<div id="content">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG CONTENT</div>
```

**EDIT: Here is another Snippet tha should do the trick:**
display:inline-block will adapt the width to the largest child element

```css
#header {
  background: red;
}
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="header">
      <p>HEADER</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I considered this solution, but because of the design, I need the div  to overflow as original posted

Comment: I added another snippet that should do the trick! Check the edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it with your design, just put your header div into the overflowing div and make it auto-fit:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <p>HEADER</p>
    </div>
  LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG CONTENT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  background: red;
}
#content {
  width:1000px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p7m8wg48/

Or make a Wrapper:

HTML:

```
<div id="bodyClass">
    <div id="header">
      <p>HEADER</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bodyClass{
  width:1000px;
}
#header {
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  background: red;
}
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLmt1Ley/

EDIT:
RE:`In your first suggestion, why did you put a fixed width? If I removed the fixed width the gap returns.`
That's because you can't set a padding to an undefined edge of an element. the width is fixed on a `before`-like state. the overflowing content resizes the actual width but it needs to be set.

Comment: In your first suggestion, why did you put a fixed width? If I removed the fixed width the gap returns.

Comment: Same with second suggestion